# ¿Como Validar input file pdf multiple?

Tags: javascript, php

tengo un formulario donde subo archivos, quisiera solo limitarlo a pdf, actualmente tengo este código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" multiple/>
<script>

$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(){
  var ext = $( this ).val().split('.').pop();
  if ($( this ).val() != '') {
    if(ext == "pdf"){
      alert("La extensión es: " + ext);
      
    }
    else
    {
      $( this ).val('');
      alert("Extensión no permitida: " + ext);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

La cual me funciona, lo que me no me funciona es que solo puede identificar los primeros y los últimos archivos, los archivos del medio no los toma en cuenta

[image: Los archivos del centro no me valida]

Comment: De hecho el codigo esta bien, si te das cuenta cuando le das al boton de examinar archivos abajo no esta seleccionado **todos los archivos (*.*)**, si no en **formato de documento portatil (pdf)**, simplemente cambia a todos los archivos y se mostrara los demas, esto se debe a que accept le da prioridad a los tipos de archivos dentro para que sea "mas rapido" buscarlos

Comment: Claro, pero me voy por el tema si es que hay alguna persona que cambie y le ponga a todos los archivos y aproveche esa vulnerabilidad para subir otro tipo de archivos

Comment: acaso no fue para eso que pusiste una condicional que si no es un archivo pdf enviara el mensaje "Extensión no permitida: " + ext? lo menciono porque probé el codigo con varios tipos de archivos y funciona como "deberia"

Comment: o ya va, lo que quieres es que de por si no se cargue el archivo que no sea pdf?

Comment: En sí como dije en mi publicación si funcionaba el js, lo que no funciona es cuando subo múltiples archivos, solo valida que sea pdf el archivo que selecciono al inicio y al final, los que están seleccionados al medio se pasan por alto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva para multiples archivos:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(){
  var fileList = $(this)[0].files || [] //registra todos los archivos
  for (file of fileList){ //una iteración de toda la vida
    ext=file.name.split('.').pop()
    console.log('>ARCHIVO: ', file.name)
    if(ext !== 'pdf'){
        console.log('>>TIPO DE ARCHIVO INCORRECTO: ', ext)
    }
    else{
        console.log('>>TIPO DE ARCHIVO PDF CORRECTO')
    }
  }
});
```

Resultados de prueba:

```
02:01:26.575 >ARCHIVO:  3-funciones-operaciones-jl.pdf 
02:01:26.578 >>TIPO DE ARCHIVO PDF CORRECTO 
02:01:26.579 >ARCHIVO:  4004.PNG 
02:01:26.579 >>TIPO DE ARCHIVO INCORRECTO:  PNG 
02:01:26.580 >ARCHIVO:  awa.xlsx 
02:01:26.581 >>TIPO DE ARCHIVO INCORRECTO:  xlsx 
02:01:26.582 >ARCHIVO:  mingw-get-setup.exe 
02:01:26.582 >>TIPO DE ARCHIVO INCORRECTO:  exe 
02:01:26.583 >ARCHIVO:  tuto1.pdf 
02:01:26.583 >>TIPO DE ARCHIVO PDF CORRECTO
```

Comment: No me funciona amigo, no se si es por la versión del jquery o por otra cosa

Comment: Que raro, yo copie el codigo que diste en la pregunta (junto al link de jquery) , y lo que pasé acá es lo que va dentro de las etiquetas de script, revisa la consola de tu navegador, allí deberian salir los console.log, use console.log en ves de alert porque me parece molesto, pero bien puedes cambiar cada console.log por un alert

Comment: Si amigo, ya lo revise bien y si me funciona perfectamente, esto es lo que buscaba, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Y en tu **HTML5** probaste `accept` ?

Podés probar algo así:

```
<form name="" method="POST" action="">   
 <input type="file" name="archivo_fls" accept=".pdf,.doc" required="" /> 
</form>
```